# Restangular query with filters

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mongodb, restangular

I have an error with my query using Restangular that is not returning my filtered data. I've tried all the below:

```
$scope.welcomes = Restangular.all("projects").getList({'name': "g"}).$object;
$scope.welcomes = Restangular.all("projects").customGET("findOne", {"filter[where][title]": "g"});
 $scope.welcomes = Restangular.one("projects").customGET({name: "g"});
 $scope.welcomes = Restangular.all("projects").customGET({name: "g"});
```

I really appreciate if you have any advice to share.

Answer (score 0):

The Restangular return data as parameter in a callback function, sample:

```
Restangular.one('user', $stateParams.id).get().then(function(response) {
            vm.users = response.data;
           // console.log('response.status:' + response.status);
        });
```

I hope this help you, or you improve the question, and i'll be back